# Mapping a function that assigns values to a list over a different list

Tags: list-manipulation

I'm trying to get used to Mathematica's approach to programming and list manipulation, and am struggling with one thing.

Say that I have a function `f` which takes a list of two values and returns a list of two values. I also have a list of doubles, `c = {{1, 2}, {1, 3}, {1, 4}, {2, 3}, {2, 4}, {3, 4}}`.

For each double in `c`, I want to return a list of four values: two of them zero, and the ones with corresponding indices in `c` should be defined by applying the function `f` to the double in `c`. Let me show some examples. For the value `{1,3}`, I would like to return `{ f[{1,3}][[1]], 0, f[{1,3}][[2]], 0 }`, and for `{2,3}`, I would like `{ 0, f[{2,3}][[1]], f[{2,3}][[2]], 0 }`.

I am completely stumped by this problem when I try to find a nice solution using `Map` and other standard Mathematica list operations. The approach that I've tried was to map over `c` trying to assign values to a list of zeroes depending on the values in `c`, but I'm lost as to how I would accomplish that. I can basically do what I want with a loop:

```
result = {};
Do[
 list = {0, 0, 0, 0};
 list[[x[[1]]]] = f[x][[1]];
 list[[x[[2]]]] = f[x][[2]];
 AppendTo[result, list],
{x, c}]
```

but I would like to learn a better approach. Here, I don't even know how to perform the operation inside the `Do` loop more elegantly, because something like

```
Map[(list[[x[[#]]]] = f [x][[#]])&, {1,2}]
```

does not work. I would appreciate any suggestions and help with this problem.

Comment: `Riffle[f@#, {0,0}]& /@ c` ?

Comment: @RayKoopman I was not clear enough with my problem, the non-zero positions in the list should not be always 1 and 3, but should instead depend on the value of c. I edited in a clarification.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Edit:* I misinterpreted the question the first time.  Hopefully I get this right now.

There is probably a cleaner way to do this, but as a start this is a bit more concise than your own loop.  (I properly localize auxiliary Symbols with `Module`.)

```
c = {{1, 2}, {1, 3}, {1, 4}, {2, 3}, {2, 4}, {3, 4}};

f = Accumulate;

Module[{a, b},
 a = ConstantArray[0, 4];
 (b = a; b[[#]] = f@#; b) & /@ c
]
```

> ```
> {{1, 3, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 4, 0}, {1, 0, 0, 5}, {0, 2, 5, 0}, {0, 2, 0, 6}, {0, 0, 3, 7}}
> ```

I used `ConstantArray[0, 4]` rather than simply `{0,0,0,0}` because it creates a packed array which will speed the replacement operations, assuming that the new elements are machine size integers.

[ssch](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/1517/ssch) offhandedly mentioned another approach using `SparseArray` which tests several times faster than my code above.  Turning both methods into generalized functions we have:

```
fn1[f_, c_] :=
 Module[{a, b},
  a = ConstantArray[0, Max@c];
  (b = a; b[[#]] = f@#; b) & /@ c
 ]

fn2[f_, c_] :=
 SparseArray[{Flatten[ConstantArray[Range@#, #2]\[Transpose]] & @@ Dimensions[c], 
      Flatten@c}\[Transpose] -> Flatten[f /@ c]] // Normal
```

Timings in version 7:

```
big = RandomChoice[Range@12, {350000, 7}];

fn1[Accumulate, big] // Timing // First
fn2[Accumulate, big] // Timing // First
```

> ```
> 0.796
>
> 0.265
> ```

---

Inspired by [A.G.](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/7060/a-g)'s answer using `UnitVector` we could also do it this way:

```
f@#.(UnitVector[4, #] & /@ #) & /@ c
```

> ```
> {{1, 3, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 4, 0}, {1, 0, 0, 5}, {0, 2, 5, 0}, {0, 2, 0, 6}, {0, 0, 3, 7}}
> ```

It is delightfully terse but quite a bit slower than the methods above:

```
fn3[f_, c_] := With[{n = Max@c}, f[#].(UnitVector[n, #] & /@ #) & /@ c]

fn3[Accumulate, big] // Timing // First
```

> ```
> 2.2
> ```

---

I realized that using `UnitVector` every time is inefficient.  Instead we can build our lists once with `IdentityMatrix` then pull the vectors needed with `Part`:

```
With[{v = IdentityMatrix[4]},
 f[#].v[[#]] & /@ c
]
```

> ```
> {{1, 3, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 4, 0}, {1, 0, 0, 5}, {0, 2, 5, 0}, {0, 2, 0, 6}, {0, 0, 3, 7}}
> ```

As a function:

```
fn4[f_, c_] := With[{v = IdentityMatrix @ Max @ c}, f[#].v[[#]] & /@ c]

fn4[Accumulate, big] // Timing // First
```

> ```
> 0.436
> ```

Second fastest so far. :-)

---

Inspired by Andre's answer here is a fifth function:

```
fn5[f_, c_] := With[{v = Table[0, {Max@c}]}, ReplacePart[v, Thread[# -> f@#]] & /@ c]

fn5[Accumulate, big] // Timing // First
```

> ```
> 3.307
> ```

Comment: I don't think the poster always want position 1 and 3, but position $c_{i1}$ and $c_{i2}$ but without the `Do`, and presumably something prettier than `f[{x_, y_}] := {fx[x, y], fy[x, y]}; Transpose@{Riffle[#, #] &@Range@Length@c, Flatten@c} -> 
   Flatten[f /@ c] // SparseArray // Normal`

Comment: @ssch Hm... you're right.  Back to the drawing board. :^)

Comment: Yes, I'm afraid @ssch is right. Thank you for your answer, though, Mr.Wizard.

Comment: @sps Sorry for not reading more carefully.  I updated my answer now; please take a look and tell me if this appears correct.

Comment: +1. This new answer looks correct to me.

Comment: Okay, I've got to leave now.

Comment: Works exactly as expected. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

Here is an improvement suggestion on you idea :

```
ClearAll[f];
f[{u_, v_}] := {f1[u, v], f2[u, v]}
c = {{1, 2}, {1, 3}, {1, 4}, {2, 3}, {2, 4}, {3, 4}};
n = Length[c];
result = {};
Do[
 list = {0, 0, 0, 0};
 With[{p = c[[i]]},
   list[[First@p]] = First@f[p];
   list[[Last@p]] = Last@f[p];]
  AppendTo[result, list], {i, n}]
result
```

with output

```
{{f1[1, 2], f2[1, 2], 0, 0}, {f1[1, 3], 0, f2[1, 3], 0},
{f1[1, 4], 0, 0, f2[1, 4]}, {0, f1[2, 3], f2[2, 3], 0}, 
{0, f1[2, 4], 0, f2[2, 4]}, {0, 0, f1[3, 4], f2[3, 4]}, 
{0, 0, f2[4, 3], f1[4, 3]}}
```

Now, come to think of it this is better :

```
c /. {i_, j_} -> First@f[{i, j}] UnitVector[4, i] + Last@f[{i, j}] UnitVector[4, j]
```

(same output)

Comment: +1 for inspiration -- see my updated answer in a few minutes

Answer (score 3):

One can use `ReplacePart[]` :

```
   c = {{1, 2}, {1, 3}, {1, 4}, {2, 3}, {2, 4}, {3, 4}}
   f = Accumulate
   ReplacePart[{0, 0, 0, 0}, {{#[[1]]} :>  f[#][[1]], {#[[2]]} :>  f[#][[2]]}] & /@ c
```

> {1, 3, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 4, 0}, {1, 0, 0, 5}, {0, 2, 5, 0}, {0, 2, 0,6}, {0, 0, 3, 7}}

**Edit**

To avoid the double evaluation of f, one can use

```
With[
 {cple = #, fcple = f[#]}, 
 ReplacePart[
      {0, 0, 0, 0},
      {{cple[[1]]} :> fcple[[1]], {cple[[2]]} :> fcple[[2]]}
      ]
 ] & /@ c
```

or use Mr. Wizard's nice solution :

```
ReplacePart[{0, 0, 0, 0}, Thread[# -> f@#]] & /@ c
```

Comment: This applies `f` twice.  One could memoize `f` but not all applications are conducive to that.  Can you find a clean way to avoid this?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I have done a edit concerning your remark. I suppose you want to avoid the double evaluation of f uniquely because of speed ?

Comment: Correct.  It is IMHO "best practice" to avoid redundant evaluation in any general purpose code.  +1

Comment: By the way this is the solution I was hoping to steer you toward: `ReplacePart[{0, 0, 0, 0}, Thread[# -> f@#]] & /@ c`